# Bash: cannot create directory with unicode character

Tags: bash, git, fonts

I am trying to checkout a git repo ([this](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)) which requires the creation of a folder with unicode characters (the name is uni¢d€), where the missing character (I don't know how to render it here) is the [Hwair gothic character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+10348). On my workstation, it works fine, but when I try to do it on a server (RedHatEnterpriseServer, where I do NOT have sudo powers), I get the error

`fatal: cannot create directory at 'python/ycm/tests/testdata/uni¢d€': Permission denied`

As a side note, I have tried to create the folder manually, and the hwair character is the only one that gives problems, meaning, that the folder `uni¢d€` can be successfully created.

The `LANG` variable is set to `en_US.UTF-8` on both systems. I have tried to find the differences between my workstation fonts and the server fonts. Grepping 'hwair', I found a font on my workstation that was missing on the server, so I copied the font folder in `~/.fonts` on the server, and ran `fc-cache`, but that didn't work.

Google-ing hwair and grepping here and there on my workstation and the server, I found out that the 'hwair' character *should* be in the Code2001 font, which I *think* should be installed on both systems, since both system  have the file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf`, which are identical, and contain the line

`<family>Code2001</family> <!-- plane1 and beyond -->`

I never really dealt with fonts at this fine level, so I'm not really sure if this is something solvable by adding some fonts locally or not (perhaps the system inhibits such particular fonts). I don't even know if copying fonts files to `~/.fonts/` and running `fc-cache` is enough or if there is something more to it.

So I guess the questions are:

1. Is the problem related to missing fonts on the server?
2. If yes, how can I add the missing font?
3. If no, is it related to something I cannot fix (perhaps it requires sudo privileges)?

Edit: the folder that cannot be created is part of the git repository. The error appears when cloning the repo (or anytime you try to checkout the master branch). I don't think there is an issue with permissions, otherwise it would fail also on my workstation (the permissions of the 'host' folder are the same). Also, trying to do `mkdir $( printf 'uni¢\xF0\x90\x8D\x88d€' )` does not work either. The bash seems indeed to interpret correctly the unicode encoding, since when printing 'cannot create...', the name of the folder DOES show the hwair symbol.

Edit2: if you think the question has some flaws, please, add a comment rather than just voting for closing. I'm happy to change/edit/improve if need be.

Comment: This is unrelated to fonts (the kernel doesn't inspect the screen so it doesn't care how glyphs show up). Which fs are you trying to create the file on?

Comment: Maybe try `mkdir $( printf 'uni¢\xF0\x90\x8D\x88d€' )`...

Comment: The error you show is `Permission denied` -- what are the permissions of the parent `testdata` directory? And all the other directories up the tree

Comment: @glennjackman It's a path within the Git repository, not a path on the server.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue!

It seems that for some - unknown to me - reason it is not possible to have that [Hwair character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+10348) in filenames on some filesystems as [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) has already mentioned.

So as a workaround I suggest that you look at the available filesystems with something like:

```
df -Th
```

and then e.g. use a symbolic link to a filesystem which uses **ext4**.

FYI: The filesystem where it didn't work for me is of type **nfs4**.